# Ram Disk for encrypting files much faster

Tags: memory, ssd, encryption, ramdisk

I have a lot of medium to small files (1gb in total) to encrypt several times a week. I often decrypt out of windows EFS then encrypt using another method. In doing so on a new fast SSD it can take 14 mins 23 secs to complete each time. However using a Ramdisk (UltraRAMDisk-Lite-1.65) 1.5 gb on size the same pc it managed it in a whopping 3 mins 30 secs.

The benchmark for the Ramdisk was far greater than even intel's 3d optane. So why would anyone ever need intel's upgrade when speed is often only needed for just some tasks. I get get that performance for free with Ramdisk. But a larger question is why hasn't windows got settings to use hardware automatically in this way? When to increase performance take little effort with what we have had for years. Then the pc can backup to ssd at leisure after the users/tasks input is finished.

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than an actual problem/question.

Comment: Windows does not know if the data is being written permanently or temporarily, or, presumably just how much data is going to be written.  OS's do there best by using caches - but their best does not imply risking dropping lots of data on the floor because we wrote it to ram disk and system died before it got to SSD...

Comment: @davidgo, operating systems are generally quite happy to let loads of data sit in the cache when there is plenty of ram.  This sounds to me like Windows is doing something stupid, like not doing proper read-ahead on EFS.  Or it may just be the biggest stupid thing Windows has always done: fragment the hell out of files as they are written.

Comment: @psusi - agreed - but I am sure they will not let data which is supposed to be written to disk it sit in cache without also flushing cache to disk.  The idea that a pc can backup to ssd at leisure after the users/tasks input is finished is inane - the OS does not know when the user has finished their tasks.

Comment: @davidgo, it will generally start writing out the data as the disk has time, but won't block further execution of programs from writing more data into the cache, so they don't get slowed down.  Unless you have disabled the write cache entirely, which Windows has an option to do for external disks so they can be safely yanked out without telling Windows first.

Comment: Why don't you use an on-the-fly encryption, like LUKS or a TrueCrypt descendant, where you can move the encrypted files/container, instead of decrypting to disk & re-encrypting? PS. RAM's always been at least 10x faster than almost any storage drive, but since you want to write to a drive that's what's happening. If you want to use a RAM disk is there anything stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts... =)

> So why would anyone ever need Intel's upgrade when speed is often only needed for just some tasks? I get get that performance for free with a RAM disk.

A couple things to consider:

- How does the operating system "know" what tasks speed is needed for? If I transform and rewrite one photo, it takes perhaps 5 seconds. If I do the same operation 500 times in a row via automation, it takes closer to 45 minutes.
- Taking a slightly contrary approach, why am I dedicating RAM (in the form of a RAM disk) to tasks that *don't* require the quickest execution possible? This seem particularly applicable in cases where a system is limited in memory for some reason.

> But a larger question is why hasn't Windows got settings to use hardware automatically in this way?

As @davidgo points out in the comments:

> [...] OS's do there best by using caches - but their best does not imply risking dropping lots of data on the floor because we wrote it to a RAM disk and the system died before it got to SSD...

RAM is volatile and even a small surge in power can effectively wipe out all its data.

Regarding a 3D Optane-like solution, the concept of "limited memory" becomes a factor again, especially in the age of mobile devices (where a Windows 10 "netbook"-style laptop can run [extremely poorly] on as little as 2GB of memory). Furthermore, why incorporate an option that is likely surpassed by third-party hardware/software?